# ERROR: integer out of range SQL state: 22003

Tags: postgresql-9.1

```
select case when MARKET_CAP_LTM > 10000 and MARKET_CAP_LTM <= 100000000 then (10000 * 1000000) * 0.25 end  from company_gics
```

While executing the above query I get the following error:

> ERROR:  integer out of range
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: integer out of range SQL state: 22003

The error occurs at `(10000 * 1000000) * 0.25` in the `case` state. Could you help me with type casting?

Comment: `(10,000 * 1,000,000) * 0.25` is the same as `2,500,000,000` - perhaps you could use that instead.

Comment: 1000000 is static filed value which is replace at dynamic

Comment: Okay then, how about optimising `(10000 * some_val) * 0.25` into `2500 * some_val`?

Comment: same exception getting